# R shiny: flowLayout with different sized boxes causes a lot of white space

Tags: r, layout, shiny

I am creating a shiny app using flowLayout with objects of different size. This works nicely when resizing the window. However, I now have more objects than I can fit in a single row. This means that some objects are moved to the second row, which causes some unwanted white space between the smaller objects. I would like the objects to be vertically adjacent, so that all white space is at the bottom. It that possible?

I have tried using fluidRow and splitLayout, but those squeeze the objects undesirably. I have also tried fixedPage and fixing the objects, but those do not have the elegance of being able to resize the window nicely.

Below is an example of a ui.R file that has this problem:

```r
ui <- function(req){
  navbarPage("Project", inverse=TRUE, theme="style.css", id = "tab",
                 tabPanel(
                   "About",
                   fluidPage(
                   flowLayout(
                     cellArgs = list(
                       style = "
                         width: 450px; 
                         height: auto;
                         border: 1px solid rgb(158,158,158);
                         box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
                         border-radius: 5px;
                         padding: 15px;
                         margin-left: -12px;
                         margin-top: 0px;
                         margin-right: 32px;
                         margin-bottom: 20px;"),
                     div(
                       h2("Getting Started"),
                       h4("Prerequisites"),
                       p("Before using the project for the first time you need to:")),

                     div(
                       h2("System Overview")
                     ),
                     div(
                       h2("Contact"),
                       h4(strong("Help"))
                       ),
                     div(
                       h2("Dictionary")

                     )                     
                   )
                   ),
                 icon=icon("cog")
                 ),
                 tabPanel(
                   "Another tab",
                   h2("Project users", align = "center"),

                   icon=icon("tint")
                 ),
                 tabPanel(
                   "Yet another tab",
                   h2("Project developers", align = "center"),                     
                   icon=icon("pagelines")
                 )
                 )
}
```